# Is "write many" equivalent to "many writes" in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I'm doing a "programming languages" course (just started) and I have this question which I honestly have no idea how to answer. I have these 2 options:

```
 write(p1, p2, ......, pn)
```

and this one:

```
 begin write(p1); write(p2); ....... write(pn); end
```

what I'm supposed to do is give an example for expressions `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn` so the program will behave differently for each of these options. I would love some help with this.

(This is not a part of some bigger program, these 2 lines are all I have.
I'm not all that familiar with Pascal, and I'm not supposed to be, that's not the intention of the course. so if you write an answer I will appreciate if you don't assume I know the language. I only know some basics.)

Comment: What about `Write(Args)` vs `Write(Text,Args)`?

Comment: @user2864740 Although your comment is absolutely valid, I don't think the tutor's intention in a "programming languages" course was to teach them that the first parameter to `write` in Pascal can be special, if it is of type `text`.  Of course, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer, as I don't think it's fair to do other people's homework.  It's sort of a hint, so that you can find the answer yourself.

At a first glance, these two pieces of code seem to be equivalent.  At a second one, they may not be.  In which order are `p1`, `p2`, ..., `pn` evaluated in each piece of code?  If the order is not (necessarily) the same, does it matter?  Can you choose `p1`, `p2`, etc. so that it matters in which order you evaluate them?

I assume that the purpose of this exercise is not to teach you Pascal, but to teach you about evaluation order and how different languages specify it (or do not specify it).

Comment: what if I take a:=0 and replace every Pi with Inc(a)? will that work?

Comment: Thinking about side effects puts you in the right track.  However, `inc` is a procedure in Pascal, so it cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: I can't use a procedure as a part of an expression? a+inc(b) for example?

Comment: No, procedure calls are statements in Pascal.  Function calls are expressions.

Comment: so I can use a function that changes the value of 'a' for example, and use it to replace Pi?

Comment: Yes, that's the way I would go.  Replace `pi` with a function call that creates a side effect on, say, a global variable `a`.  But be careful; what will the result of the function be?

Comment: I was hoping for some simple expression that won't require additional functions. but if I do use a function, can't I receive the "a" as a reference using var and then "return" "a" as the result?

Comment: Yes, you can write your own `incAndUse` function that has the same semantics as, say, a prefix `++` in C, with a `var` (call-by-reference) parameter.  This will do the trick.  But your answer to this homework question has to include a discussion of evaluation order and why it is different between the two alternatives.  That's what is important here, not the side effects themselves.  If you have that, I think you're done.

Comment: yeah, obviously. but with the explanation I also need an example that will work. thanx. I now need to figure out how to do the same with "read" instead of "write"

Comment: someone suggested for the write function, to replace Pi with a function that prints "hi" and returns 0. it sounds right. the first option will print "hihi00" and the second "hi0hi0". is that true?

Comment: There are several types of side effects.  Variable access (read/write) is one.  I/O is another.  Yes, this will also work.  In fact, you may see why this answer is better than `incAndUse`; what would happen if Pascal specified (or your compiler implemented) left-to-right evaluation for arguments?

Comment: I don't see how will it make a difference in this case, the order of evaluation.

Comment: That's true, it will not.  On the other hand, in the version with `incAndUse`, both pieces of code will behave the same if argument evaluation is left-to-right.